# pygame.midi.Input.read can't being a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pygame, midi

i'm on Ubuntu 20, and I use Python 3.9.
I can't put the list of `pygame.midi.Input.read` to a string, because else, my programm is closed with the output:

`pygame 1.9.6`

`Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html`

`[[[248, 0, 0, 0], 1]]`

`Exception: b"PortMidi: Bad pointer'"`

`Exception ignored in: 'pypm.Input.__dealloc__'`

`Exception: b"PortMidi: Bad pointer'"`

so, here, it work:

`def truc(myinput):`

`while True:`

`if myinput.poll():`

`event = str(myinput.read(3))`

`print(event)`

`pygame.midi.init()`

`my_input = pygame.midi.Input(3)`

`truc(my_input)`

but if I add this after the `print(event)`, he won't work

`if '1' in event:`

`print('ok')`

`else:`

`return`

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM FOUNDED:

If you got this problem, you just have to **don't put any `return`**

See ya